# UI grid trigger a function when filter is applied

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Angular UI grid.

My requirement is to trigger a function when ever some one applied a filter on the grid.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to the `filterChanged` event when you register the gridApi.

```
gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
    $scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function(){
         // your logic goes here
    }
}
```